# What is DPT in the context of a firewall log?

Tags: networking, firewall, mac

I'm not a server admin, but I'm trying to work out why a colleague can't connect to the internet. The settings she's using are exactly the same as everyone else, but she can't connect. We're all Mac people and running OS X 10.5. One thing I noticed after looking at the firewall logs is that connections from everyone has a DPT of 137, wheras her machine has a number above 40000. Is this normal and what does it mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DPT=Destination PorT

UPD Port 137 is NETBIOS service port, but if you aren't an admin network...it will be hard to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

DPT = Destination Port as lg mentions.

Port 137 typically is the NetBIOS Name Service which is not unusual in a firewall log, but I doubt that it's got anything to do with your user's problem.

What you want to look for in the firewall logs will vary depending on what services you're allowing through your firewall and what the firewall's logging configuration is.  It's possible to configure the firewall to not log things.

If you can post a little more about what exactly "connect to the Internet" means in your context then we'll be able to help a bit more.  Are you talking about web browsing, ftp, SSH, etc...?